# AWS Cloud Formation multiple route entries with parameters

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

There is a requirement for cloudformation template to have mutiple route entries to route table.
AWS::EC2::route can create only one route entry.
Is there a way to create mutiple route entry which depends on parameters?
Example in parameter a comma separate or list of destination cidr will be asked and target will be IGW

Parameters
DestinationCidrList:
Type: String
Default: 172.16.2.2\32, 10.4.14.3\32

The cfn template should create routes in routetable to IGW, this destination list can have mutiple  destination IP address

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using AWS Macros PyPlate
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/PyPlate/

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  RouteEntries:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "10.2.3.10/32,0.0.0.0/32"

  ResourceName:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "ip1,ip2"

Transform: [PyPlate]

Resources: |
  #!PyPlate
  output = {}
  for ip in params['RouteEntries']:
    for name in params['ResourceName']:
      output[name] = { "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route", "Properties": {"RouteTableId": "<RT ID>" , "DestinationCidrBlock": ip, "GatewayId": "<IGW ID>" }}
```